# Start an Activity from a BroadcastReceiver with a result

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I can call an Activity from a BroadcastReceiver by this way:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        try {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);

            Log.v(TAG, "alarm triggered");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This brings the app to the front and calls `onResume()` at the Activity. My problem is I can't determine if the BroadcastReceiver brought me to `onResume()` or just the user itself by hand. Is there any way I can be sure that the BroadcastReceiver called the Activity?

I also tried to fill the Intent at the BroadcastReceiver with Extras by doing `i.putExtra("foo", "bar")`. I couldn't read it out by calling `MyActivity.getIntent().getExtras().get("foo")` at the Activity.

Hope somebody can help me with this issue, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send extras in your intent and check them onReceive but proper way of doing this would be to set a boolean value for "STARTED_BY_RECEIVER";

When starting the activity, throw the third line into your onReceive callback method;

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("STARTED_BY_RECEIVER", true);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Then in the onCreate of the activity, you can check if this was started by the broadcast receiver like this;

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("STARTED_BY_RECEIVER")){
    // The activity was started by the receiver
}
else{
   // The activity was started by user
```

This would work because the getBoolean method would return false when there's no extra called "STARTED_BY_RECEIVER", this way you only have to put the flag in the one place (started by receiver)

Also don't forget to the put the "STARTED_BY_RECEIVER" in a static variable and use that in both places!

Comment: What do you mean by putting the "STARTED_BY_RECEIVER" in a static variable and use that in both places? As is see there is no variable STARTED_BY_RECEIVER I could check by the normal way like `STARTED_BY_RECEIVER == true;` This didn't work for me, I did everything you said but the "static variable"-thing. The case `if(getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("STARTED_BY_RECEIVER"))` never happens although I did `i.putExtra("STARTED_BY_RECEIVER", true)` in my BroacastReceiver.

Comment: Ok forget about the static thing.. You put the if() in the onCreate right? If it's called from the receiver, it will be true so the if clause will run, if called by user then else will run because there won't be a ("STARTED_BY_RECEIVER") extra in there.. Now you need to be as thorough as I was in my answer and tell me what didn't work, it doesn't help to just say "This didn't work for me"

Comment: In the `onReceive()` method at my BroadcastReceiver i set `i.putExtra("STARTED_BY_RECEIVER", true);` before I start the activity by `context.startActivity(i)`.

At my Activity I put `if(getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("STARTED_BY_RECEIVER"))` into my `onCreate()` method but the if clause never gets true.

That's what I did, sorry for beeing improper and thank you for your participation.

Comment: I have this in my code and it works.. The only thing i can think of is that that activity might not be getting called from the broadcaster.. Can you confirm that your broadcast receiver is starting the activity (it will never be true if it's not being called from there). Can you debug and step through the onReceive method()?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that because the Activity is getting brought to the foreground. `onReceiver()` is definately called. I don't know if this is wanted by stackoverflow.com but could you please mail me your working soultion? Maybe I have forgotten something essential and can help users who forgot it too by posting what I did wrong.

Comment: Sorry but everything you need is there.. I'm certain that this should work as intended, unfortunately I can't send you my code as it contains alot more stuff. You should really look into debugging and stepping through the code. Check the spellings of "STARTED_BY_BROADCASTER"...  Also you can copy paste the code into your question, and I will take a look at it

Comment: Okay It works now. I got `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in my AndroidManifest. Apparently it prevents `onCreate` to be called.

Comment: Oh great.. Yeah singleTask forces the same activity to restart rather than a new one being created. Glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast receivers cant pass extras
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

You could try to do it in reverse though, have the user action of opening the activity pass a boolean set to true as default value the you can check for

```
boolean userStarted = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean('userStarted', false);
```

Comment: But where shall I set userStarted? I need some case where I can be sure the user resumed the activity and not the BroadcastReceiver. It's the same issue in reverse.