# android: passing something back to activity from a broadcast reciever

Tags: android

so i have this problem where i have something to pass back to the activity, but the problem is i don't know how, i've read some threads but its a bit cloudy and confusing, can anyone of your shed some light about this. i just want to pass something back to the activity from my reciever (BroadcastReciever). I have read a thread that you can start an activity but the problem is that there is a bit of a confusion if passing an extra on your intent to an activity is allowed?. Thanks for any inputs any of you could provide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass data from a BroadcastReceiver through to an Activity being started?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616859/how-do-i-pass-data-from-a-broadcastreceiver-through-to-an-activity-being-started)

Comment: I guess the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8597528/1434631 may help you..

Comment: yep i've read both those thread, im still confused if onResume() is really called or what, and if yes, i'll put something to the onResume() isntead of in the onCreate()

Comment: anyone knows how to pass something without starting an activity, cuz in my app, activity is already started, i just want to send something to that started activity, cuz starting an activity that is already started is kinda redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6857648/760489

you can do this way by setting flag in intent when you start the activity from broadcast receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    Intent i = new Intent(context, DestinationActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    i.putExtra("PATH", path);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

The FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP makes sure the apps doesn't re-open if already open. This means that the "old" intent that opened YourActivity in the first place is re-used and it will NOT contain the extra values. You have to catch them in another method called onNewIntent() in YourActivity.

Check out the complete answer from top link

Comment: shouldn't be setFlags() instead of addFlags? cuz i got mine working using ur algo but im using setFlags(), addFlags() does nothing on my case..

Comment: decided to accept this answer its the closet thing i've got, just changed the addFlags to setFlags, but still my question stays the same as above

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    Intent i = new Intent(context, DestinationActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("PATH", path);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: not really, already know this process what i'm after is passing something without starting an activty, cuz in my app the activty is already started

Comment: @lemoncodes-Then it will come in front...no harm in that...but if u need to pass it without affecting ur GUI, then use Services !!